# asciidoctor(-pdf) exclude content from pdf only

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I have an mydocument.adoc document including a link to the pdf version of itself,
How to not include it in the pdf itself, (generated using asciidoctor-pdf)
... still including it when generating the html-5 version, using asciidoctor ?

```
// tag::pdflink[]
link:mydocument.pdf[pdf version,window=_blank]
// end::pdflink[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conditionally exclude (or include) content, you need to use [conditionals](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/conditionals/).

When you run `asciidoctor`, the default converter (aka the "backend") is `html5`. You can wrap the content you want to exclude in a conditional that checks the intrinsic `backend` attribute:

```
ifeval::["{backend}" == "html5"]
link:mydocument.pdf[pdf version,window=_blank]
endif::[]
```

For any other backend, such as the `pdf` backend, that link won't be included.

See [intrinsic attributes](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/document-attributes-reference/#intrinsic-attributes) for other attributes that `asciidoctor` sets automatically for you. Any of them can be used in conditionals.